# Having error on JOIN

Tags: firebird

This is a Firebird database.

First Table

Contacts
Company_ID - job_title

Second Table

Client_id - Co_name

In contacts, I want to the job_title field to contain the co_name.

client_id and company_id are the same. 
Co_name correspond to company_id as well as client_id.

this:

```
UPDATE Contacts
SET Contacts.Job_title = Clients.co_name
WHERE
    company_id IN (
        SELECT
            client_id
        FROM
            clients
        JOIN Contacts c ON Client_id = company_id
        WHERE
            record_status = 'A'
    )
```

gives me an error as cannot find (clients.co_name)

this other option:

```
UPDATE Contacts
JOIN Clients ON Clients.Client_id = Contacts.Client_id
SET Contacts.Job_title = Clients.Client_name
```

gives me an error on JOIN

Any other ideas please?

Thank you all

Comment: please don't repost - edit your existing question.

Comment: i would still expand it over there and discuss it with the person who submitted the answer.

Comment: ok I will Daniel.. just trying to woprk out how to edit the previous :O

Comment: There is an edit button below the question

Answer (score 0):

Possibly already answered here: [Update records in one table using another table's records as WHERE parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655720/sql-firebird-fdb-update-records-in-one-table-using-another-tables-records-a/26687454#26687454) - looks like it should work, but I'm not a Firebird expert.

The code from that answer (but look for more context, and alternative answers):

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Column1 = NULL
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 
    FROM Table2 
    WHERE Table2.Column2 = Table1.Column2)
```

(couldn't flag question as duplicate because that question has no upvoted or accepted answer)